# The import org.springframework.beans.Beanutils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 4.3.3.RELEASE in my project.

As per spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/)

I can see BeanUtils is in `package org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`

Now when I try to reference

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
```

[image]
[image]

I am getting error by eclipse

> The import org.springframework.beans.Beanutils cannot be resolved

However when I change to `spring 4.2.2.RELEASE` it works fine?

So my question is that since its there in `4.3.3` why its showing as error.

Comment: till now you are asked 4 questions but not accepted any answers..but comments says it's worked...accept the answers so that it is helpful to others

Comment: Check the `spring-beans-X.X.X.jar` file that's in your classpath, to verify that it contains the `org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.class` file.

Comment: @Andreas, I have attached image which shows BeanUtils.class is there

Comment: Show all referenced jars

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of typing mistake.

> As per [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/package-summary.html) it is **`BeanUtils`** not `Beanutils;` `U` letter caps.
>
> `BeanUtils` *is not a package* to show in the suggestion, it is a `Abstract Class` so type `ctrl+space` after `.` (i.e `org.springframework.beans.ctrl+space`)

Use `import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;`

And it is **`BeanUtils`** from spring 1.0 to till now.

Comment: No still facing same issue.

Comment: How come..check your classpath make sure `Spring-beans` jar is refered

Comment: As you can see eclipse autocomplete also not showing beanutils.

Comment: @timtom `import org.springframework.beans.Beanutils` here it saying Beanutils not BeanUtils....U letter caps

Comment: Check your second image,it is showing BeanUtils class...R u sure you dont have two jars of same version in your projct?  and try by clean and build..

Comment: Checked once again , only one version of jar is loaded and did clean build also ..gettiing same error

Comment: I can see commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar is also getting loaded.It contains BeanUtils.class, but I am not sure from where its getting loaded

Comment: remove that from classpath..keep only spring beans...but that should not affect(if both are referenced)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building with eclipse and maven use the command as mvn eclipse:eclipse.

Comment: It shows build success with mvn eclipse:eclipse, however not able to run it

Comment: can you remove the spring jars after that close the eclipse. Again open the eclipse and only 4.3.3 jars